# Using session to return message only returns one message

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, validation

So I have a sign up form. One is the `register.php`, which is the actual form. And the other is `r.php`, which process it. So I use sessions to that then I send the error message from `r.php` to `register.php`. The issue is for some reason I can only figure out how to display *one*

```
if($name === ''){
    $_SESSION['name_req'] = 'Make sure to enter a name';
    header('Location: register.php');
    exit();
}
elseif($name > 255){
    $_SESSION['name_len'] = 'Enter a shorter name';
    header('Location: register.php');
    exit()
}
```

This code basically sends the message to `register.php` then I display the error with

```
<?php echo isset($_SESSION['name_req']) ? $_SESSION['name_req'] : '';?>
```

The issue is if I it'll only display one error at a time and I want to display all of them at once. Any ideas?

Comment: all codes after `exit()` are not executed!

Comment: So if I get rid if it, it should be good? @Bellash

Comment: Session variables last as long as the browserwindow is opened if not edited manualy. Be sure to unset the session somewhere in your code or else the message may even be displayed if there is no error.

Comment: Might be a typo but you are missing `strlen()` on your $name length check.

Comment: I am aware of that an I'm using `<?php unset($_SESSION['message']);?>` to unset it @MarkNijboer

Comment: Just fixed that,thanks. I added it to other parts of my code but not this part. @cOle2

Answer (score 2):

With just the code you supply, the page redirects if just one error is found, try this instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitbuttonname']) && $_POST['submitbuttonname'] == "submitbuttonvalue") {
    if($name === ''){
        $_SESSION['name_req'] = 'Make sure to enter a name';
    }
    if($name > 255){
        $_SESSION['name_len'] = 'Enter a shorter name';
    }

    header('Location: register.php');
    exit();
}
```

but if you use javascript to submit the form, the submit button won't work, instead you can just use a hidden input with whatever name and value you want.

Comment: How do you suggest I check if the form has been submitted?

Comment: if the submit button has a name, just check either $_POST['name'] or $_GET['name'] depending on the method of the form. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Or he can use `if(!empty($_POST)) {` this means any form has been submitted. Note: not good for multiple forms page...

Comment: So something like this? `if(isset($_POST['name']))`

Comment: ya that would work, also make sure the form is set to post and not get. you can use $_request to get it either way, but its best to use post or get at least for the initial check.

Comment: For some reason its not working. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/HxfgRZeb) my full code

Comment: you have to get rid of the elseif statements and make them all their own if statements. the elseif statements only run if none of the previous if / elseif statements returned true.

Comment: also, depending on the php configuration, you either are not going to see the echos before the redirect, or the echos are going to stop the redirect.

Comment: I'd assume something like [this](http://pastebin.com/Mw4gfHa1)? But it still isn't working.

Comment: Yep, and also remove the `header('Location: register.php');` and `exit()` code from everywhere except the end

Comment: I get sent to `r.php`, then when I go back to `register.php` I see the message.

Comment: I don't want to go to r.php at all if there are errors

Comment: This is probably because you are echoing some of the error messages. If this code is on r.php, then the redirect may get cancelled if anything is echoed or written outside of the <?php ?> tags. If you do not want the user to ever see this page then make sure you do not echo anything, and put a redirect at the bottom after all of the code.

Comment: I then get this `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/matt/Desktop/Like/r.php:1) in /Users/matt/Desktop/Like/r.php on line 74`.....

Comment: Line 74 is `header('Location: register.php');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56368/discussion-between-user3100859-and-jstephen).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sessionValue   = array();
$redirectTo     = "register.php";
if($name === '')
{
    $sessionValue[]       = 'Make sure to enter a name';
}
if($name > 255)
{
    $sessionValue[]       = 'Enter a shorter name';
}
$impSessionVal            = implode("|",$sessionValue);
if($impSessionVal!="")
{
    $_SESSION["errormsg"] = $impSessionVal;
    header("Location: $redirectTo");
    exit();
}
```

while displaying errors, explode the session message with | and get individual messages.